# Configure Notepad++ DBGP plugin and XDebug for PHP

Tags: php, plugins, notepad++, xdebug

I followed these steps:

1. download x-debug*.dll to D:\Program Files\webserver\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
2. modify php.ini and insert following

   ```
   zend_extension_ts="D:\Program Files\webserver\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
   xdebug.remote_enable=1
   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
   xdebug.remote_mode=req
   xdebug.idekey=default
   xdebug.remote_autostart=1
   ```
3. restart apache and XDebug is successfully installed.
4. DBGP is installed successfully and configured with 127.0.0.1

but XDebugger is still not connecting/working with notepad++.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

i found the answer here

> http://thecancerus.com/debugging-php-using-xdebug-and-notepad-part-i/

Make sure you have latest version of Notepad++ is installed.

1. Download the latest release of [DBGp Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/DBGP%20Plugin/DBGP%20Plugin%20v0.13%20beta/).
2. Unzip and move dbgpPlugin.dll file to plugins folder of your notepad++ installation folder, in my case the path is “C:Program FilesNotepad++plugins”.
3. Check out the readme.txt file, that is bundled with plugin, to make sure we don’t miss anything.
4. Now open Notepad++, and you should see DBGp option in plugins menu.
5. We are now almost finished with setup, only thing remaining is to configure DBGP to listen to right port and we are done.
6. Goto “Plugins->DBGp->Config” to open the configuration screen of DBGp plugin.
   [image]
7. IDE KEY should be same to the one you specified in php.ini settings above. Click Ok and you are done.
8. To start debugging just add “?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=session_name” at end of you url. ‘session_name’ could be anything you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the steps given in the link which you have provided. It worked perfectly.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 4):

XDebug now have their very own wizard.

http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

All you have to do is copy and paste the contents of your phpinfo output into it. It'll provide you with the correct library and the details that you need to add to your php.ini.

Dont forget that you have to append your URL with `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=name` to kick things off.

Comment: One way to get php info:

`<?php`
`phpinfo();`
`?>`